# How to use WinHelp (.hlp) using .NET Help API?

Tags: .net, winhelp

I am saddled with WinHelp format (.hlp) files and need to invoke them from a .NET 3.5 DLL.  I can get the file to launch but am unable to get either TopicId or Topic to work.  The file always opens to the "Getting Started" topic.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a HelpProvider component, then you need to set the HelpNavigator property to Topic, the HelpNameSpace property to the help file path, and the HelpKeyword property to be the topic (full path within the help file).